# CString format with Unicode returns wrong character

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to format a CString using the following code:

```
const wchar_t * wch = L"μ";
CString str;
str.Format(_T("%c"), wch[0]);
```

However, instead of str having the value of "μ" it actually is set to "¼". When I debug it, it recognizes wch as "μ".

Further, if I do:

```
const wchar_t * wch = L"μ";
CString str;
str.Format(_T("%s"), wch);
```

it gives str with value "¼". (It doesn't seem to show up but there should be a superscript L after the ¼.)

The compiler is set to use unicode, as else where in the program I am able to call _T() and have it evaluate correctly, just not when formatting a CString.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit: ** Doing more debugging shows that the CString Format method's arglist receives a value of "Ü_"

Comment: is it possible you are misinterpreting what you are seeing?  The UNICODE character `μ` is 0x03BC.  Interpret that as two single byte characters and you get `¼` which is 0xBC and superscript L which is 0x03.

Comment: Are you compiling your application with UNICODE and _UNICODE?  Is your source file saved as ANSI or UTF-8?  Have you tried using CStringW explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to use a "long" char or string format specifier -- so `%lc` for the `wchar_t` and `%ls` or `%S` for the string.

Comment: that doesn't seem to help. using `%lc` gives me an empty string and `%ls` or `%S` throws an error

Comment: @jonbooz : His suggestion is the correct one, and works fine for me with VC++ 2010. You may need to post more code...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

before calling Format.  (Unless you're doing anything unusual, it's enough to call setlocale once near the beginning of your application.)

Answer (score 0):

I see `Miu` with `%c` and with `%lc`

```
// a1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <afx.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const wchar_t * wch = L"μ";
    CString str;
    str.Format(_T("%c"), wch[0]);
    MessageBox( GetForegroundWindow(), str.GetBuffer(), L"MyChar", MB_OK + MB_ICONHAND );
    str.Format(_T("%s"), wch);
    MessageBox( GetForegroundWindow(), str.GetBuffer(), L"MyChar", MB_OK + MB_ICONHAND );
    return 0;
}
```